# Transactions / request-response-pattern in flow based/reactive programming

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, reactive-programming, flow-based-programming

So I have been reading about flow based programming (FBP) in the last few days and I have also been reading J. Paul Morrison's book about it. However I feel I still can't really wrap my head around it. The general concept is that you see programming as some sort of assembly line where you have components that take some packet as input and produce some packets as output. You can connect these components and packets travel through the network. While I totally see how this can work for ETL type applications or batch processing, I have no good idea how you could handle things like synchronous request/response patterns or database transactions with it.

For example let's say I have a web server implemented as FPB. This webserver has a GET /user/{id} which should return a JSON with some information about a user. It also has a POST /user/{id} where you can update the user by sending some JSON back to the server. So here is how I would imagine this flow to be looking:

[image: Example Flow]

I tried to have many re-usable components instead of putting the whole logic of handling a request into a single component. So there is a HTTP server component which sends out requests to a dispatcher component which then dispatches the requests into subsequent flows. In each flow the request is parsed by a generic "Request parser" component which outputs various parts of the request into the rest of the flow.

The upper part is quite straightforward, I read the entity of the user with the given ID from DB, serialize the object to JSON and then send it back. However at this point we don't really have a reference to the HTTP request anymore, so how would I know where to send this request to?

On the lower part we have some additional complexity because I would like to write to the database in a transactional way. So first a transaction is started (in parallel the request body is parsed into some object), then the user object is retrieved from the database and merged with the inputs from the request. At the end it is written back to the database and the transaction is committed. Finally some "OK" status is responded to the caller. Here I have the additional problem that when committing the transaction I really don't know which transaction to commit. And of course when sending the response I don't know which request to send it to.

So both problems seem to have something in common -  a kind of "Context" that spans over many components. On one example it is a HTTP request/response context in the other a transactional context. In regular programming, these contexts are usually handled at the thread level. Since a request runs in a single thread, the transaction and request contexts are bound to a thread-local so they can be accessed everywhere as long as everything is running in the same thread.

In flow based programming, every component runs independently and ideally on separate threads. This is actually a key thing because it allows for parallelization and effective use of multiple processors. However when that thread-local context is no longer there, how can you handle these problems in flow based programming? This would get even more complicated with proper error handling (which I left out in my example).

I figure that when you do reactive style programming where most of the processing is asynchronous and multithreaded as well you will have the same issues, so I wonder if there are patterns to handle this. Do you have real life experience with either reactive style programming or flow based programming and have some hints on how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick answer on Twitter - thought I would post it here as well... Apologies for double-posting!

I like substreams for this/these problem(s), where the first Information Packet in the substream provides the "context" you were talking about.  This may help: https://github.com/jpaulm/javafbp-websockets...  HTH!

PS This loop-style network topology is also the basis of Facebook's new "Flux" technology - see Jing Chen's presentation, in which she compares this approach with MVC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this may nudge you in the right direction. I had a similar issue where I  needed to perform a synchronous operation in an asynchronous microservice architecture.

How I solved it was using the Observer pattern. I have 3 components; a http server, a callback server and a timer wheel. The http server similar to yours receives the incoming request, the callback server receives the overal result after asynchronous processing and the timer wheel that queues the original http context and reconciles the response to the http request.

When an incoming request is received, the http server creates a correlation id ,appends it to the request metadata, appends the callback server url to the request metadata and finally adds the request and the original http context together into the timer wheel. Then the http server would pass the request to the dispatcher like in your case and send messages to the relevant components for asynchronous processing.

Depending on the outcome of execution of the current processing component, it will retrieve the callback url from the metadata and send the response to the callback server.In your case there's the json serialization or the database write that would do this. The callback server will then extract the correlation Id that was appended and get the corresponding http context and write the response.

NB each timer object in the timer wheel has a timeout that's configurable, that way if the asynchronous processing delays it will timeout and return a configurable message to the http client of the corresponding http context.